# How to set nested object in django rest framework?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

first of all, this is not about creating or updating nesting objects, but only about setting them. lets use the following example: I have the following models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    code= models.CharField(max_length=2)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Question(models.Model):
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='categories')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and the following serializers:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('code', 'name')

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category= CategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('category', 'title')
```

Now, when I `get` a `Question`, its fine working as expected : I get the question fields with he category fields as expected.

The problem that I have is when I want to `post` a `Question` only having the `Category.code`, I am not really sure how to set/use an existing `Category`. I have been trying different ways, but none of them worked.

If I remove `category= CategorySerializer()` on the `QuestionSerializer` and I pass the `id` (`pk`) of the `Category` in my request, than it is working, the `Question` is saved with the related `Category`.

Is there any way to indicate how to serialize the nested object?

Thank you in advance for any comment/advise/solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django REST Framework: create and update an object with a nested object value (instead of Primary Key)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181118/django-rest-framework-create-and-update-an-object-with-a-nested-object-value-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I got it. To me it seems that it is about creating `Question`, right?

You can overwrite the `create` method of `QuestionSerializer`

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category= CategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('category', 'title')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        category = validated_data.pop('category')
        category_obj = Category.objects.get(code=category['code'])

        return self.Meta.model.objects.create(category=category, **validated_date)
```

Maybe you also have to set the field `name` in `CategorySerializer` to `read_only`

Comment: I specifically said that is not about creating or updating a nested object in my first sentence. it is about using an existing one.

Comment: @storm_buster That's what this answer does (mine covers both cases). It creates a new _Question_, but will query to find an existing _Category_ to attach to the Question instance.

Comment: @storm_buster when you `post` data the `create` method of a serializer gets called. Or do you mean a `PATCH/PUT` request? Then you should do a similar thing as described above with the `update` method.

Comment: I get that, I can use `post/put/patch` with the `pk`, without overriding the `create` or the `update` method. I am just asking here if there is a quick way if use another field other than the `pk`.